# simple printf case

Tags: c, printf

I want to blink `*` (star) on my Linux terminal window, so I thought of using ANSI control codes and in loop first write `*` then after `sleep(1)` write `" "` (blank-space/empty-string) but it does not work - cannot see anything. Why ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void blink(){
    while(1){
        printf("\033[2;2H*");
        sleep(1);
        printf("\033[2;2H ");
    }
}

int main(void){
    blink();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to flush `stdout`, it is buffered by default (and you should sleep a bit after the clear too, otherwise you won't see anything).

```
while(1){
    printf("\033[2;2H*");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\033[2;2H ");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard output is line buffered. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void blink(){
    while(1){
        printf("\033[2;2H*");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        printf("\033[2;2H ");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void){
    blink();
    return 0;
}
```